# Accents in TeXworks

Tags: accents, input-encodings

I am using TeXworks to write documents, but as I am doing some stuff in spanish, accents are required. When I write

```
áéíóú
```

I get

```
Ã¡Ã c
```

If I do `\'a \'e \'i \'o \'u`  I get the desired result `áéíóú`

I have changed in Edit->preferences->Editor->Coding->ISO-8859-1 
instead of UTF-8 but get the same results.

Comment: you are missing a `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to load the package `inputenc` with the current encoding or the package `selinput`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
áéíóú
\end{document}
```

Example with `selinput`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
adieresis={ä},
Euro={€},
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
áéíóú
\end{document}
```

You see this behavior is independent from the editor.

Comment: I just wanted to add that, in my case, Texworks editor was not loading `accents` when I was trying to open the `.tex` file with accents. However, by simply changing the encoding:  Edit->preferences->Editor->Coding->ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 solved the problem.